# How to obtain the real number of file descriptors used by this process with psutil?

Tags: python, psutil

I'm currently testing the psutil API.
When I run this command (in order to know the number of number of file descriptors)  with:

```
p = psutil.Process(PID)
p.num_fds()
```

I get 70 file descriptors.

However, when I run this command with the same PID:

```
p.open_files()
```

I only get 27.

What's the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `open_files()` returns regular files only but a process may open many other kinds of fds (sockets, pipes, etc). A tool like lsof reports all of them. I decided not to do the same in psutil because it's too complex, too low level and not portable by using a consistent API.